# Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect(), Mysql and php

Tags: mysql

I am working with Apache, XAMP and MySQL with my mac and I get this error message:

> Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect().

Been googling it for a bit but I am still stuck.

I have added these lines in the two of my php.ini files. I find them in XAMPP/etc and i add these "codes" in both of the ini files:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll 
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

I restart the apache servers but I still get the error message.

Any clues?

Do I have to use a PDO instead? When I read into it it seems like *sqlsrv* only works for Windows? Do I need to download anything or is just pasting the code inside the ini enough?